# Wind Turbine Model Setup --> determining if it is in series or parallel if a multimeter is connected

Tags: electric-circuits

I have a wind turbine setup in which two wires (red and black) are connected to a generator. On the other ends of the wire, alligator clips are holding a 10 ohm resistor. Each alligator clip is also holding a probe from a multimeter that is the same color as itself. I need to calculate the total resistance, so I was wondering if this setup is considered to be connected in series or parallel since the multimeter *is* involved. In other words, does the multimeter being connected cause the entire setup to be in parallel?

Refer to this picture: [image: Setup Diagram]

Comment: If the multimeter is a standard device operating in voltage measurement mode it will have a very high impedence. This so that it has no significant effect on the circuit and can be typcally ignored. Basically ignore it in your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I find it very interesting when the colours of the wires are mentioned. Did you know that the electrons don't know the colour of the wire they travel down and the multimeter, alligator clips, generator etc also do not have any eyes. In fact the only things that see the colours of wires are humans and if you have one that does not understand the circuit then knowing which bits are red, black or even gamboge is not going to help.

To get back to the question series and parallel are only relevant when you have defined the 2 or more electrical "things". E.G. Resistor A is in parallel with Capacitor B. OR Bulb A and Bulb B are connected in series and attached to a battery. What are the 2 or more things you want to consider in your diagram as being in series or parallel. Please define the "things".